# Как растянуть GridLayout на всю ширину родителя, чтобы при этом столбцы занимали все пространство по ширине?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-xml

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как растянуть GridLayout на всю ширину родителя, чтобы при этом получилось три равных колоны, которые занимают все свободное пространство по ширине, а не сбиваются к правому краю, а пол-экрана (по ширине) остается пустым.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.andrei.counter.MainActivity">

    <GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnCount="3"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button1"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:onClick="onButton1"
            android:text="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button2"
            android:onClick="onButton2"
            android:text="2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button3"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:onClick="onButton3"
            android:text="3" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button4"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:onClick="onButton4"
            android:text="4" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button5"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:onClick="onButton5"
            android:text="5" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button6"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:onClick="onButton6"
            android:text="6" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button7"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:onClick="onButton7"
            android:text="7" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button8"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:onClick="onButton8"
            android:text="8" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button9"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:onClick="onButton9"
            android:text="9" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button0"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:onClick="onButton0"
            android:text="0" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ButtonEnter"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:onClick="onButtonEnter"
            android:text="enter" />
    </GridLayout>



</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пространством макетов в GridLayout можно управлять с помощью `android:layout_columnWeight="1"`, наглядный пример можно увидеть в этом [вопросе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47028842/stretching-column-width-to-fill-all-the-available-space-in-gridlayout).

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:onClick="onButton1"
        android:text="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:onClick="onButton2"
        android:text="2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:onClick="onButton3"
        android:text="3"
        tools:targetApi="lollipop" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:onClick="onButton4"
        android:text="4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:onClick="onButton5"
        android:text="5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:onClick="onButton6"
        android:text="6" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:onClick="onButton7"
        android:text="7" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:onClick="onButton8"
        android:text="8" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:onClick="onButton9"
        android:text="9" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button0"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:onClick="onButton0"
        android:text="0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ButtonEnter"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:onClick="onButtonEnter"
        android:text="enter" />
</GridLayout>
```

Теперь ваши кнопки расположены ровно и занимают всю ширину экрана. Единственный минус это `Attribute layout_columnWeight is only used in API level 21 and higher`при использовании `android:layout_columnWeight="1"`.

Comment: для API < 21 всегда можно использовать `'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:27.0.2'` (добавить `compile` в `gradle`) . В разметке использовать `android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout` и  `app:layout_columnWeight` (в нужном `View`)